# The script for two factor authentication for getting code from local DB

Tags: java, database, selenium, two-factor-authentication

My application requires automation.
first it automatically enters username and password and clicks login button
then a OTP code which is already stored in database and it automatically fetch Static OTP code from database and enter in to OTP Text field then it allows user to enter into the application. if you have an automation script, please provide it.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

JDBC does not support local DB connection. My workaround is using SQL CMD utility.

```
public static String localdbInstanceName = "YOUR LOCAL DB INSTANCE NAME";
public static String sqlCmdCommandPreffix = "sqlcmd -S " + localdbInstanceName + " -E -d master -Q ";

// method to recieve result text from CMD command 
public static List<String> getCmdResults(String command, Boolean wait, Boolean printResults, Boolean printErrors) {
    int exitCode = - 1;
    List<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();
    Process process;
    BufferedReader bufferedReader;
    InputStreamReader inputStreamReader;
    String p1 = null;
    String p2 = null;
    try {
        process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
        inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream());
        bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
        String line;
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            if (line.trim().length() > 0) {
                results.add(line.trim());
            }
        }
        p1 = System.lineSeparator() + command + System.lineSeparator() + System.lineSeparator();
        p2 = String.join(System.lineSeparator(), results) + System.lineSeparator() + System.lineSeparator();
        if (printResults) {
            log.info(p1 + p2);
        }
        if (wait) {
            try {
                exitCode = process.waitFor();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {                  
            }
        }
        else {
            exitCode = process.exitValue();
        }
        if (exitCode != 0 && printErrors) {
            log.error(p1 + p2);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return results;
}

    // example with specific query
    public static String getStartOnStartPage(String dbName, String userId, String regId) {
        String q1 = "SELECT Value FROM [" + dbName + "].[dbo].[Parameter] ";
        String q2 = "WHERE Variable = 'StartOnStartPage' AND UserId = " + userId + " AND IdRegistrace = " + regId + ";";
        List<String> results = getCmdResults(sqlCmdCommandPreffix + "\"" + q1 + q2 + "\"", false, false, true);
        if (results.size() > 0) {
            return results.get(0);
        }
        else {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

For SQL Server express you can use this:

```
public static List<String> getSqlResults(Connection connection, String query, String key) {
    List<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();
    try {
        Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
        statement.setQueryTimeout(60);
        ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery(query);
        while (result.next()) {
            results.add(result.getString(key));
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return results;
}

public static Map<String, String> mapSqlResults(Connection connection, String query, String key, String value) {
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    ResultSet result = null;
    try {
        result = connection.createStatement().executeQuery(query);
        while (result.next()) {
            map.put(result.getString(key), result.getString(value));
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return map;
}
```